# I can't open the pgAdmin app on my system

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

It is pgAdmin4 for 64-bit OS. My windows version is also 64 bit.
It says:
Fatal Error
The application server could not be contacted.
I wanted to create a database in it so that I could work with psycog1 library.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the right version for Windows, simply uninstall it. then google the window setup for installing Postgresql and follow it through, make sure you note your details while setting up and installing. Right after installation, go to your Windows search bar, search for PgAdmin, then enter, it might fail in the first trial, but go ahead and try it again.

Comment: ok. now right click pgadmin and run as administrator.